# How to construct matrices/vectors from a table in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, iteration

I'm quite new to R, and if I imported a .csv file and if rows represent

time and columns represent n variables of interest, how could I construct a

function that returns any given 1xn vector from the table?

P.S. I'm not just interested in constructing a vector, but I will perform 
matrix algebra with iterative calculations to estimate parameters, which means 
I will need to use a for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data structure contains e.g. m rows and n columns i.e. n variables, you can easily construct the n vectors without much effort.

```
data<-read.csv(".../file.csv")
class(data)
[1] "data.frame"
class(as.numeric(data[1,]))
[1] "numeric"
```

So it is not a big deal to convert 1*n matrix i.e. vector of length(ncol(data)).
In a loop just use

```
data["required Row Number",]
```

to access the particular row. Each case it will ultimately give 1*n matrix or a vector of length(n)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `melt()` from the package `reshape2`

Or if you want to use the `for` loop, try something like:

```
one_col <- data[,1]
for (i in 2:ncol(data)){
   one_col <- rbind(one_col, data[,i])
}
```